# Playbook doesn't fail with EC2 when no hosts return

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

Usually ansible playbook task fails when there's no host found when using static inventory. But when using EC2.py and when there's no host returns playbook doesn't fail which prevents us from notifying that task has not been run on particular instance with automated tasks.

Below is the output of playbook when no host found

```
PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************

Finished: SUCCESS
```

Have anyone come across this issue or is there's any option to change its behavior? please help

Comment: "*Usually ansible playbook task fails when there's no host found when using static inventory.*" - taken literally it might be true - if a host was specified and not found=not reachable, Ansible fails - but it's not what you ask about in the next sentence. Ansible finishes without any error if plays were not executed because they were supposed to be running against an empty host groups. You need to rethink your process.

Comment: @techraf thank you for clarifying. Do you have any suggestions or workaroud?

Comment: As I mentioned, you need to rethink your process. If your tests/auditing/compliance is dependent on the output of a single script, something is wrong in the way you manage IT. That's not really a problem for StackOverflow.

Comment: @techraf why, if ansible is perfectly capable of do assertions on it's own configuration

Comment: @SztupY Why what?

Comment: @techraf why do you think adding an additional layer to reporting is beneficial and less error-prone if the problem can be solved using the task that's already being used (in this case ansible)

Comment: @SztupY Why are you asking me this question? I stated what I stated above. If you don't agree state the opposite: that depending on a single script (with the assumption that no error is an indicator of everything being ok) is the best way to manage complex IT infrastructure and let's go our ways.

Comment: @techraf the problem I have is at some occurrence ansible didn't pick up the instance even though instant is available and running. If the task then end with success in a pipeline we need to assume it ran properly. So adding verification task will fail and we can investigate

Answer (score 0):

Even if there are no hosts in the inventory at all you can still run code against `localhost`.

So run some checks against `localhost`:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: No hosts found in us-gov-west-1 region
      when: (groups['us-gov-west-1'] is undefined) or (groups['us-gov-west-1'] | length == 0)
      failed_when: true
```

This will for example fail, if your generated inventory contains no hosts inside the `us-gov-west-1` group. You can potentially do other checks, like check that there are at least `n` entries there, etc.

You can add checks like this at the start or end of your playbook, which will make sure ansible will fail if some of the preconditions are not met.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll test this and revert back